# User Not Authorised to login the console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-console

While I tried IBM MobileFirstPlatform [V6.3], I am not able to login to console. This is the development server comes with the studio.

I didn't configure the administrative security for console.
I didn't add/modify any user.

Error Log as follows

```
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin:worklightRealm while invoking WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/EvidencerMob/applications. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin:worklightRealm while invoking WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/EvidencerMob/applications. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightConsole on /index.html. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightConsole on /services. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightConsole on /index.html. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking WorklightConsole on /services. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].
```

Comment: Is this the development server that comes with MobileFirst Studio? Or the "full" MobileFirst product? How have you configured the administrative security for the console? Please edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

The MobileFirst console, in the MobileFirst Development Server (the developer edition available as an Eclipse plug-in), does not require any login. In case for some reason a login *is* required, the credentials to use are admin/admin.

It's unclear to me why you got this error, but one possible way around this is to:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Open the Eclipse workspace and delete the MobileFirstConfigServer folder
3. Open Eclipse again, start the server and visit the console